# Can .NET CORE CLI - load arguments from file?

Tags: c#, .net-core, command-line-interface, dotnet-cli, dotnet-sdk

I am using .net cli 2.0.3 and I was wondering if it is possible to load my arguments from file i.e.

`dotnet publish -args somefile`

Where `somefile` will contain the arguments which the certain command accepts.
For example, while publishing I want to have predefined `path\project.csproj -c Release -o "outputpath"`

I know that there isn't that kind of command in the sdk, but is there a way that I can achieve it ?

Best regards!

Comment: Its always best to prefer the "Config way" i.e using the appsettings.json file for situations like this. Do you have a different kind of requirement?

Comment: you can write a script ps1 OR sh depending on your env. Which reads the file and then calls the dotnet cli.
see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1955505/parsing-json-with-unix-tools

Comment: @RakshithSm this isn't a question about the *application's* configuration, it's about passing arguments to the CLI tools. A settings file can't handle multiple environments and containers by the way. There's no single "best" way, all options have their place

Comment: I want something like vscode task.json, but I don't know what is the utility that is parsing it and executing it.

Comment: @IvanRuski sounds like you are looking for [publishing profiles](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/visual-studio-publish-profiles?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x#publish-profiles)? Once you create a publishing profile you can pass it to `dotnet publish` as an MSBuild parameter with `/p:p:PublishProfile=<ProfileName>`

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos, yes exactly. `dotnet publish -h` does not shows the information you've provided.
Thanks, that answers my question :)

Comment: @IvanRuski that's because it's an MSBuild feature, not a feature of `dotnet publish`

Comment: @IvanRuski VS also [has tasks files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/customize-build-and-debug-tasks-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017) but I haven't used them

Comment: Thanks I will make use of both links

Comment: all msbuild based CLI commands don't show all the options that msbuild allows for. one of them is response files, see my answer. you'd need to know a few of the CLI->MSbuild translations (e.g. `-r win-x64` => `-p:RuntimeIdentifier=win-x64` etc.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While the CLI itself doesn't have a mechanism to load response files, it calls out to MSBuild which does support both specified response files and the following automatic response files:

1. `MSBuild.rsp` next to the project / solution file to build
2. `Directory.Build.rsp` in the hierarchy at or above the project / solution file to build

While you cannot specify CLI arguments, you can specify their equivalent MSBuild arguments.

For example you can create a `release.rsp` next to your solution file that specifies:

```
-p:Configuration=Release
-p:OutputPath=..\rel-out\
-p:PublishDir=..\pub-out\
```

Which you could use to call

```
dotnet publish test\project.csproj @release.rsp
```

If the same file was named `Directory.Build.rsp`, it would have been applied automatically.
If would also have been applied autoamatically if it was named `MSbuild.rsp` and put it next to the csproj file.